# How to arrange Java abstract class hierachy and polymorphic method call and definition

Tags: java, swing, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I was experimenting with making some simple `Swing` classes and I stumbled across a question about how i should best arrange calls to methods that are implemented in concrete classes implementing abstract classes.

Currently I have the top-most parent of a small hierarchy of abstract classes and concrete classes calling the abstract (at the top-most and second level level) `addComponents()` method of classes that are intended as the children of this hierarchy. This presented a query regarding where one should define and call such a method, since the intention of this was to place the definition of such a method within the classes that extend the children of the hierarchy.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractFieldPanel extends JPanel

public abstract class BorderedFieldPanel extends AbstractFieldPanel

public class ExampleDataPanel extends BorderedFieldPanel

public class FieldPanel extends AbstractFieldPanel
```

I would like to specify the details of which components are to be added in the classes that extend `BorderedFieldPanel`and `AbstractFieldPanel` in the implementation of the previously `abstract addComponents()` method.

The call to the `addComponents()` mehtod is thus `abstract` where it is defined in `BorderedFieldPanel`and `AbstractFieldPanel`.

The concrete implementations of the `addComponents()` method are located in the `ExampleDataPanel` and `FieldPanel`, which were the intended instances of their use.

The question i have, is whether i was right under polymorphic reasons to put the call to the abstract methods in the constructor of the highest class in the hierarchy `AbstractFieldPanel`, or whether it should be called from the constructor of the lowest class in the hierarchy?

I assumed initially that this is good *OO* design, taking advantage of inheritance and the polymorphic properties and delegation of abstract classes.

Though, if this is correct, this must present problems (in some cases) when considering that the `super()` constructor is called explicitly or implicitly on the first line of the extending classes. Thus it somehow does not feel like necessarily the correct thing to do from a design point of view and I was hoping to ask for advice on how this should best be approached.

Comment: Calling overridable methods from a constructor is not a good idea: the method in the subclass will be called on an object that is not constructed yet.

Comment: thanks, i though it sounded wrong for reasons including that.

Comment: Can anyone perhaps advice me on how I should redesign it? All of these classes need to call this method. Especailly since they are methods relating to how the object is composed, i am a little confused since i would expect this to be behaviour called from within some sort of constructor somewhere within the hierachy?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that these components are added when the object is created, then you could make them an argument in the constructor of `AbstractFieldPanel` (instead of a no-args constructor). That would mean that the sub-classes constructors would have to call `super(components)` passing a collection of component objects to the super-class constructor. Then `AbstractFieldPanel` would actually add the components it was given.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'd prefer composition over inheritance, why not have an interface, which contains `addComponents()` and have your **concrete** classes implement that?

*Warning, personal opinion*
Abstract classes are (to me) a code smell, since it's mostly used to keep code DRY in subclasses, creating artificial, nonfunctional classes ('what is the purpose of this class, what does it do? An abstract class does nothing, cannot do anything, since it's not complete.'). Harder to test, leads to duplicate tests (methods are tested from all subclasses, instead of only once). Of course, there are cases where it's actually useful, but I prefer loosely coupled code so it's easier to test.